# How to implement camera flyby in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Let's say the width of a level in my game is three times the screen width, and my player starts at the left most edge. How should I go about implementing a camera flyby starting from the right edge at the beginning of this level to scroll through the entire world so the player knows what to expect ahead?

I came across this post here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9568 that seems to be useful, borrowed the block of code in it and put it in my `GameWorldLayer`, but it didn't work. I'm essentially only seeing a black screen. What's wrong? And what would be a better way of implementing this?

```
-(void)visit {
    CGSize screenDims = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSizeInPixels];
    CGPoint camPos = gameCamera.position;
    float camZoom = gameCamera.zoom;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setProjection:kCCDirectorProjectionCustom];

    //now set your projection
    kmGLMatrixMode(KM_GL_PROJECTION);
    //save current projection state
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    kmGLLoadIdentity();

    kmMat4 orthoMat;
    kmMat4OrthographicProjection(&orthoMat,
         camPos.x -screenDims.width/(2*camZoom),
         camPos.x +screenDims.width/(2*camZoom),
         camPos.y +screenDims.height/(2*camZoom),
         camPos.y -screenDims.height/(2*camZoom),
         -1000,
         1000);

    kmGLMatrixMode(KM_GL_MODELVIEW);
    kmGLLoadIdentity();

    [super visit];

    //put it back
    kmGLMatrixMode(KM_GL_PROJECTION);
    kmGLPopMatrix();
    kmGLMatrixMode(KM_GL_MODELVIEW);
    kmGLLoadIdentity();
}
```

Comment: I think you are right...I might have been overthinking this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is way to complicated for what you want. Position the layer at the end of the level at the beginning and then simply move it to the beginning i.e.

```
[layer runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:10 position:ccp(starty, startx)]];
```

Where 20 is the time you want it to take for the "flyby" and the position is the start position